Google OAuth2 Error 400: invalid_request for Chrome Extension Redirect URI
I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication in my Chrome extension, and I'm encountering an issue with the redirect URI. My redirect URI is in the format chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/callback.html. However, when I try to initiate the OAuth2 flow, I receive the following error:
Error 400: invalid_request
Parameters: redirect_uri=chrome-extension://beenjehedsfaeisfngidmffpnhglbgka/callback.html flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

@GetMapping("/url")
public ResponseEntity<UrlDto> auth() {
    String url = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(clientId, "chrome-extension://beenjehedsfaeisfngidmffpnhglbgka/callback.html", Arrays.asList("email", "profile", "openid")).build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new UrlDto(url));
}

I also tried using this redirect: redirectUri https://beejjehedgdaeiafngidmffpnhglbgkg.chromiumapp.org/
But i got:
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
Parameters: flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

